# Getting the raw query text from graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment in Java

Tags: java, graphql

In a resolver's code, I have an `graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment` object.
Is it possible to get the raw query text from it?
I couldn't find a way to do it.

Thanks!